# facebook like jquery card hover with pointing end and available space

Tags: jquery, facebook, tooltip, jquery-hover

i am trying to create the facebook like hover card when u hover over someone from say the chat.

the way you get an pointy arrow pointing towards the person and his info.

now from this page

```
http://reseller.linkall.co.in/
```

i have managed to edit out some amount of code and made the mouse movement not follow it

```
http://jsfiddle.net/UYCUu/
```

but i cant make it get the pointy part and to decide weather to show left or right depending on available space.

any help is appreciated guys

Comment: im sure i can but dunno how exactly to

Answer (score 0):

you can surely create arrows using css... Please refer the below link for more info:
https://www.slateone.com/directory/slates/slate_list/0/525

you can also create the hover using Jquery and css. The below link can provide you some inputs on the same.
https://www.slateone.com/directory/slates/slate_list/0/571